# Auth Filter Not Working

Tags: authentication, laravel, filter, laravel-routing

Trying to use `auth` filter to keep users from accessing certain routes without being logged in. The code below redirects regardless of the user's status. I was unable to find anywhere what to put within the function. I'm using http://laravel.com/docs/security#protecting-routes for reference. Not sure if I should have an if statement or not. Not sure what to do at all.

Route:

```
Route::get('/account', ['before' => 'auth', function() 
{
    //  continue to /account
}]);
```

Standard 'auth' filter from `app/filters`:

```
 Route::filter('auth', function()
 {
 if (Auth::guest())
 {
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
    else
    {
        //return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
}
});
```

The way I understand it the code within the function should only be loaded if the user is logged in. Otherwise give 401 error.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from my friend I fixed it. Some important information, Route filters will continue with intended purpose unless something is returned from filter. Also, the standard auth filter will not work. Must be modified. After that it was cake. Code is below.

Route:

```
Route::get('/account', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'SiteController@account']);
```

Auth Filter:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
});
```